# Regular expression to require exactly two spaces in result

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, soapui

Regular expression to allow only two spaces in result. Example: "one hundred dollars" contains only two spaces and if there is more than 2 spaces then condition should be failed

Example: two three thousand four hundred fifty five

contains more than 2 spaces and therefore condition should be failed

Comment: What kind of assertion you are trying to apply? Is `Script Assertion` or `Xpath`?

Comment: You may take a look that answer and accept the suitable one for you.

Comment: Xpath in Contains

Comment: How does your raw response look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below is the regular expression which accepts the string with 3 words and 2 space

```
/^([A-Za-z])+\s([A-Za-z])+\s([A-Za-z]+)$/
```

Explanation

- ^ : Start of the string
- ([A-Za-z]+) : accepts word with one or
  character
- \s : white space
- $ : end of the string

Answer (score 0):

use **\s** to detect white space.

for example, to accept "I am student" or "one hundred dollars" you can have..

> /^ [A-Za-z]+ \s [A-Za-z]+ \s [A-Za-z]+ $/

Although I am not sure it works.. I didnt check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the groovy script which does the assertion that you are looking for.

```
//String sample to test both negative and positive tests

//This string should fail the test
​def string1 = 'two three thousand four hundred fifty five'

//this string should pass validation
def string2 = 'two three thousand'

//Expected space count
def expectedSpaces = 2
//Check for number of occurances of spaces in the given string
def group1 = (string1 =~​ /\s/)
def group2 = (string2 =~ /\s/ )

println "${string2} has ${group2.size()} spaces"
println "${string1} has ${group1.size()} spaces"

//Positive assertion
assert expectedSpaces == group2.size(), "${string2} failed assertion"
//You may find this failing as expected, so negative assertion
assert expectedSpaces != group1.size(), "${string1} failed assertion"​
```

You may quickly check this [script](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5160787203063808).